# Is there a way to disable sound in one program?

Tags: sound

Is there a way for me to be able to enable sound in one program (say, VLC) and at the same time disable sound in another program (say, chrome).

I am not using these programs in particular. The question is in general.

Answer (score 37):

If you click on the sound icon in the top bar (at least in 12.04) and go to **Sound Settings > Applications**, then you can adjust the sound for each application individually. You can see in the screenshot that I have two programs open at the same time. The top one is Firefox playing a YouTube video and I was able to mute it separately.

[image: screenshot of sound settings]

A downside of this method is that not all applications appear there. As far as I know, it's only for those which use ALSA. Just give it a try, it works fine for me with some programs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 20.10 you can do the following:

1. Click the top right hand corner of the screen, where the battery, sound and wifi icons are located.
2. Click on **Settings**

   [image: Top Bar & Settings Menu]
3. When the Popup menu comes up, navigate down to the **Sound** tab on the left hand side of the the Settings menu.

   [image: Settings Menu]
4. Looking under **Volume Levels** You can see a list of open windows and the main system sound. Feel free adjust them as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **PulseAudio Volume Control** as an alternative solution

[image]

It also provides the options to filter between: **Applications**, All Streams and Virtual Streams

Installation: `sudo apt install pulseaudio` and `sudo apt install pavucontrol` **for GUI**