# How do I control the volume of individual programs that are not actively playing sound?

Tags: sound, 22.04, volume-control

I want to be able to control the volume of individual applications. In the volume control in system settings, as well as PulseAudio Volume Control (what I found through [similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513748/adjust-volume-level-of-individual-application) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114122/is-there-a-way-to-disable-sound-in-one-program)), only programs that are actively playing sound at that given moment show up. This is incredibly unhelpful as certain programs play sound but only briefly, e.g. the notification sounds on Discord. How do I actually change the volume for ANY PROGRAM that is open/running?

Ubuntu 22.04